# FIFO queue display issues

Tags: java

When adding a name to the text field it is vertical however when I remove a user from the queue, it changes horizontally. Secondly I am having issues with changing the position of the user. When the user is removed from queue, I would like the user below to take their position e.g. 1. Harry, 2. Tom, 3. Greg (Remove Button).
1. Tom, 2. Greg.

Comment: "When adding a name to the text field it is vertical however when I remove a user from the queue, it changes horizontally." - What do you mean by this?  Also the Javadoc prefers you use an ArrayDeque to a LinkedList when implementing a Queue.

Comment: Can you add a bit more code, I think the vertical -> horizontal is happening because of the different ways you append ("\n") to the text areas. jButton2ActionPerformed should iterate the elements and append "\n" the same way jButton1ActionPerformed does. What do you mean by 'issues with changing the position'?

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys, so the problem with the position change is that the person below should take first position, but what it is doing is that it is pushing the person below to the first position keeping their current number

Comment: So person who holds position 1 will be deleted, person B will take their position in the actual linked list but will still be shown as position 2 on the text area. I think you will only be able to fully understand if you run the program above

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of your code you are not taking the actual index, You have taken "count" as reference variable and displaying in both add and remove. Check the following code for your expected result:

```
private static Queue<String> myQ = new LinkedList<String>();

    private static JTextField jTextField1 = null;
    private static JTextArea jTextArea1 = null;

    private static void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        String name = jTextField1.getText(); // get text from text field
        jTextArea1.setText(""); // remove all text in text area
        myQ.add(name);// add text field data
        int count = 0;
        for (String str : myQ) { // iterate
            jTextArea1.append(count + " " + str + "\n");// append into text area
            count++;
        }
        System.out.print(myQ);
    }

    private static void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        myQ.remove();
        System.out.print(myQ);
        jTextArea1.setText("");
        Iterator it = myQ.iterator();
        int count = 0;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Object e = it.next();

            jTextArea1.append(count + " " + e + "\n");
            count++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Button Example");
        jTextField1 = new JTextField();
        jTextField1.setBounds(50, 50, 150, 20);

        JButton addUsersButton = new JButton("Add User");
        addUsersButton.setBounds(50, 100, 95, 30);

        JButton removeUsersButton = new JButton("Remove User");
        removeUsersButton.setBounds(150, 100, 95, 30);

        jTextArea1 = new JTextArea();
        jTextArea1.setBounds(60, 150, 200, 200);

        addUsersButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(e);

            }
        });

        removeUsersButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(e);

            }
        });

        f.add(addUsersButton);
        f.add(removeUsersButton);
        f.add(jTextField1);
        f.add(jTextArea1);
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
```